# Unable to import from root directory to subdirectory without modifying sys.path (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror

## What I have tried

First let me say, I have read maybe 5 or 6 other stackoverflow questions related to this and many things have been said about this. Here's what I found and what I tried:

1. "Do `sys.path.append(<root dir>)` before other imports."

   **Issue:** This works, but it's against PEP standard practice so I'd rather find a solution that does not require modifying `sys.path`.
2. "Use the `imp` library to find your module."

   **Issue:** The solution outlined in that answer is deprecated as `importlib` is the new `imp`, and I'm not sure how to use `importlib` even after looking at the docs.
3. "Add an empty `__init__.py` file in your root directory."

   **Issue:** This does not work.

## Details of my problem

Here is my file structure:

```
Project/
  ├ subdir/
  |   └ script.py
  ├ __init__.py
  └ module.py
```

(Note that I left the empty `__init__.py` file in there just in case it's needed.)

#### I'm trying to import from `module.py` to `subdir/script.py`:

Contents of `module.py`:

```python
def func():
    print('func was called')
```

Contents of `subdir/script.py`:

```python
from module import func
func()
```

However, when I run `python3 script.py` in terminal (on Mac), I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module import func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

I would appreciate a straightforward solution that does not require modifying `sys.path`.

Comment: check this , this will help you. 

https://stackabuse.com/python-modules-creating-importing-and-sharing/

You need to create a module that can be install  as python package.  and you can import from python package .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: I appreciate all the solutions. I've opted to use the `sys.path` hack even though it is bad practice in general, because my project is just too small to be worth all the effort of creating a setup file, a virtual env, and a pip install just so I can import one module. I thought there would be a quick AND pythonic solution, but since there isn't, I choose quick over pythonic. In the future, I will use your solutions for larger projects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to solve your problem is to restructure your project:

```
Project
   ├── script.py
   └── module
         ├── __init__.py
         └── module.py
```

Comment: This seems to be the least work and most pythonic solution, however unfortunately I'm not willing to compromise the current structure of my project. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by setting `PYTHONPATH`. In my case, it works with this.

```
PYTHONPATH=<root dir> python3 subdir/script.py
```